# Should closed duplicates show up differently in search?

Tags: feature-request, search, duplicate-questions

Here's a quick feature suggestion, I think it would be helpful if a duplicate question which comes up during search will actually contain a visible link to the "canonical" question which it's a duplicate off.

Moreover, it would make sense (I don't know if it's implemented yet) that a question whose multiple duplicates show up in search to be ranked higher. After all, there's a high chance that what the user is searching for will have an answer if 50 duplicates of the same question appear in his search query.

What do you guys think?